# Запаздывает input[checkbox] в EDGE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

В общем есть такой код

```css
.button {
  background: url(http://imgur.com/OqeWzGn.png) -143px -38px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-position: -161px -38px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="sde" class="button" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('checked')"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="asd" id="sde">
```

В Edge input отстает от label. И иногда получается так что на label `checked`, а на input нет. А в остальных все нормально

Comment: А как происходит событие checked  и как оно связано css. Потому как по представленному коду это непонятно.

Comment: Мне желательно чтобы чсли checkbox `checked` то label имеет класc .checked

Comment: Может есть смысл использовать css конструкцию типа input:checked + label {} .тогда можно повесить свой стиль,  который, например, используется в классе .checked.

Comment: не работает ` input:checked + label {}`

Comment: Потому что в html структуре input должен быть выше label :)

Comment: @Alex78191 всё правильно он написал, именно так и нужно стилизовать checkbox

Comment: Согласен, это не ерунда.

Comment: @andreymal это не решает вопрос

Comment: решает на удивление

Comment: @Alex78191 решает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.button {
  background: url(http://imgur.com/OqeWzGn.png) -143px -38px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked ~ label{
  background-position: -161px -38px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="asd" id="sde">
<label for="sde" class="button" ></label>
```

Comment: Кстати в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683279/182273) в IE галка у label быстрее показывается.

Answer (score -1):

Можно и без атрибута `for` сделать. IE некорректно обрабатывает множественное нажатие на checkbox.

```css
.button {
  background: url(http://imgur.com/OqeWzGn.png) -143px -38px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-position: -161px -38px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="button" onclick="$(this).toggleClass('checked'); $('#sde').prop('checked', !$('#sde').prop('checked'))"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="asd" id="sde">
```

Comment: А зачем для id [0]?

Comment: @Duoxx чтобы получить элемент

Comment: Эмм id уникален если что

Comment: @Duoxx функция `$('')` возвращает не HTML элемент.

Comment: @Duoxx переписал на Vanilla jQuery.